# Correct grammar

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure

Saying,"where is Valerie at?'is incorrect grammar. Ending a sentence with preposition is incorrect. But why? When asking the question where is something the sentence is usually ending with at and you don't end a sentence with preposition at. Why? It's so common

Comment: Side note: I suggest not giving questions vague, general titles like "correct grammar". That title could describe almost any question that would be appropriate to ask on this site. A better title would have been, "Ending a sentence with a preposition", or "What's wrong with 'where is Valerie at?", etc.

Comment: Using 'at' in this way is a modern speech pattern; not one that will be understood by everybody. "Where is Valerie at?" is more a question of mental state than physical location. Similarly "Where's your head at?" is not enquiring about the location of your skull, but your current mental state, or preparedness for a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, in this example, the "at" is superfluous. You could just ask, "Where is Valerie?" "At" adds nothing of value to the sentence.

Two, many reject the rule that you should not use a preposition to end a sentence with. (Hee hee.) The reason behind the rule is that a preposition requires an object. Like if you say "behind", you have to say what it is that the thing is behind. If I just said, "The box is behind", behind what? Normally the object of a preposition follows the preposition. So usually if you end a sentence with a preposition, that means you have not specified the object.

The problem with that thinking is that it treats a "usually" as "always". Sometimes we vary the normal word order. Like consider my sarcastic sentence, "Never use a preposition to end a sentence with." It's not true that the preposition "with" has no object just because it is at the end of a sentence. It's object is "preposition". I could have said, "Never end a sentence with a preposition." But it's not clear why that would be superior to the sentence I did write.

Following the rule sometimes leads to writing contorted sentences. Someone once criticized Winston Churchill for breaking this rule and he replied, "That is a rule up with which I shall not put." Of course most people would say, "That is a rule I shall not put up with". But that ends with a preposition. So to avoid breaking the rule we need a convoluted sentence like Churchill's. The sentence that follows the rule is more complicated and difficult to understand than the sentence that does not follow the rule. When a grammar rule forces you to write complex and confusing sentences just to obey the rule, there's a problem with the rule.

But all that said, it doesn't apply to this case. You can just say, "Where is Valerie?" You don't need to add the preposition "at" because the fact that you are asking for a location is already conveyed by the use of the word "where". If you really wanted to include the word "at", you could ask, "At what place is Valerie?" or some such, but why?

Comment: The Winston S Churchill first arose as a humorous tale about a high school English teacher in 1941, and by 1943 it was connected to Winston Churchill. The modern version emerged by 1946. There is no evidence WSC ever said it, or anything like it.

Comment: There are lots of things WSC was supposed to have said, but didn't.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Ok, fair enough. I was going to type, "Winston Churchill was reported to have said ..." but decided to drop the equivocation. I don't claim to have done any research to determine whether Churchill really said it or not. Clever quotes often get attributed to famous people so I wouldn't be shocked to learn that he never said it, or if he did, he was quoting someone else.